# Why is AbortController part of the DOM specification?

Tags: javascript, dom

`AbortController` is used to cancel HTTP requests but it is specified in the [DOM specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-abortcontroller).

Canceling HTTP requests doesn't seem like a DOM operation like `Events`. Why is it defined in, and part of DOM specs? Shouldn't it be part of Web APIs?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think some HTTPRequest stuff is built into the DOM -- specifically regarding form submission, so maybe the DOM also needs to be able to handle canceling any interactions with the server that it initiates. Just spitballing.